# Leetcode twoSum question using C "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c

I'm trying to practice C using Leetcode and below is my solution to twoSum: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

I've tested my solution using gcc in a Linux VM and the code compiles with no warnings and also gives the right solution(only tested with some simple cases).

However, when I try to run the same code on Leetcode, I keep getting:
"error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] "

Can someone please explain what's the issue with my code?

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    
    int result[2];
    int *result_ptr;
    result_ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    result_ptr=result;
    
    int i=numsSize-2;
    
    while(nums[numsSize-1] + nums[i] != target && i != 0){
        i--;
    } 
    
    //value found
    if (i!=0 ||nums[numsSize-1] + nums[i] == target){
        result[0]=nums[numsSize-1];
        result[1]=nums[i];
        return result_ptr;
    }
    else{//value not found
        if(numsSize>2){
            twoSum(nums,numsSize-1,target,returnSize);
        }
        else{
            //premise states there will always be a solution
            //so this should never be reached
            return result_ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you think the assignment `result_ptr=result` does, but it probably won't work as you expect. It leads to a memory leak, and that you return a pointer to a local array. A local array whose life-time will end when the function returns and make the pointer immediately invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the advice! I used a separated pointer because the premise mentioned I have to malloc for the returned value(and a free() will be called for me). Also, in my understanding, result will be a pointer to the first element of the array and result_ptr=result will simply have result_ptr point to the same element, can you kindly explain why this may be problematic? Thank you!

Comment: First `result_ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)*2)` makes `result_ptr` point to the memory you just allocate. ***But*** then `result_ptr=result` makes `result_ptr` point somewhere else. The original value of `result_ptr` is lost. It's like `int x; x = 5; x = 10;` and then wonder why `x` isn't equal to `5` any more.

Answer (score 0):

You have *multiple* problems in the code you show.

First we have the issues mentioned in my comments. First of all the *reassignment* of `result_ptr` makes you loose the original pointer, so you no longer have access to the memory you allocated with `malloc`. This is known as a *memory leak*.

The reassignment also leads to other problems, like you returning a pointer to the local `result` array. An array which will cease to exist immediately when the function return, making the returned pointer invalid.

It *also* leads to problem when the code later tries to `free` the returned pointer, as the pointer you return isn't returned by `malloc` (or other memory-allocation function).

The solution to all of these problems is to not have the array `result` *at all*. Remove it, use `result_ptr` as the array.

---

Then for the error message you get.

In the code you have

```
if(numsSize>2){
    twoSum(nums,numsSize-1,target,returnSize);
}
else{
    //premise states there will always be a solution
    //so this should never be reached
    return result_ptr;
}
```

Here you only explicitly return from the function in *one* branch. The other, where you call `twoSum` recursively, doesn't return at all. Instead the code will continue beyond the `if`, and run to the end of the function. And that means the function won't return a value, leading to the error message.

If a function is declared to return a value, it *must* return a value, explicitly and using the `return` statement. This problem is solved by returning what the recursive call returns:

```
if(numsSize>2){
    // Explicitly return the result of the recursive call
    return twoSum(nums,numsSize-1,target,returnSize);
}
else{
    //premise states there will always be a solution
    //so this should never be reached
    return result_ptr;
}
```